# How to get all pages on specific blog after switch_to_blog?

Tags: multisite, switch-to-blog

I am attempting to loop through all sites on my `multisite network` blog. However, when I attempt to use `get_pages` it ignores the fact that the blog has switched via `switch_to_blog`.

```
$sites = wp_get_sites( array( 'limit' => 1000 ) );
foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
    $blog_id = intval( $site['blog_id'] );
    if ( $blog_id < 2 ) {
        continue;
    }
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
    $pages = get_pages( array(
        'sort_order' => 'asc',
        'sort_column' => 'ID',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ) );
    echo 'Blog ID: ' . get_current_blog_id() . ' | Total Pages: ' . count ( $pages ) . '<br>';
    // foreach( $pages as $page ) {
    //  echo 'Blog ID: ' . $blog_id . ' | Post ID: ' . $page->ID . '<br>';
    // }
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

Output:

```
Blog ID: 2  | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 3  | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 4  | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 5  | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 6  | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 7  | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 8  | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 9  | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 10 | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 11 | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 12 | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 13 | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 14 | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 15 | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 16 | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 17 | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 18 | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 19 | Total Pages: 71
Blog ID: 20 | Total Pages: 71
```

The script above will var_dump the same `$pages` through out the entire loop, regardless of which blog it switches to. What exactly am I doing wrong, and is there a way to accomplish what I'm attempting to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `get_posts` instead of `get_pages`

```
$pages = get_posts( array(
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ) );
```

Comment: Hi there, could you elaborate further?

Comment: Try with the code I added...

Answer (score 0):

Question is old, but for anyone with similar issue, this should work for you:

```
<?php

$sites = get_sites([
    'number' => 9999,
]);

foreach ($sites as $site) {
    switch_to_blog($site->blog_id);

    $pages = get_pages();
    echo count($pages);

    restore_current_blog();
}
```

wp_get_sites was deprecated in 4.6 in favor of [get_sites](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sites/)